# По какому правилу ставится запятая? Нигде не могу найти ответ!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, бессоюзное

"Ты же говорил, у тебя нет денег!"
Вообще, по какому такому правилу стоит запятая? По логике это бессоюзное предложение - запятая в нем ставится только при перечислении. Так почему здесь стоит запятая? Кто-нибудь, подскажите, буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это предложение **по значению** сложноподчинённое с придаточным изъяснительным. Ср.:*Ты же говорил, [что] у тебя нет денег!*

В вашем  примере просто опущен союз *что*.

Да, **по форме** предложение стало сложным бессоюзным. Но по смыслу оно так и осталось сложноподчинённым: *Ты же говорил (что? о чём?), у тебя нет денег!*

Второе предложение короткое, относится к глаголу со значением речи *говорил*, стиль разговорный, поэтому ставим запятую, а не двоеточие.

***Ты мне говорил, у тебя какой-то детальки не хватает, не помнишь, какой? – Какой детальки? – Какой-то передней… [Сергей Носов. Грачи улетели (2005)]*** - пример из Нацкорпуса РЯ.

Comment: А можно ссылку на правило про разговорный стиль? Пожалуйста!)

Comment: Говоря о  разговорном стиле, я имела в виду особенность произнесения такого рода предложений: в них отсутствует интонация предупреждения и пауза, характерная для предложений с двоеточием. "Если первое предложение произносится без оттенка предупреждения и паузы (с полным интонационным слиянием частей), то вместо двоеточия ставится запятая.

Например: Слышу, земля задрожала. (Н.) Помню, ты дитей с ним часто танцевала. (Гр.)" https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/305